What is the maximum variance direction of a binary mask of the letter T?
I am performing a PCA analysis on a binary mask with the aim of determining the major axis of the shape. I am trying to understand if the first eigenvector generated in this process makes sense. Should the first eigenvector point towards the top of the T?
